# MAMP Htaccess password protection: "Authentication required" dialog being repeated

Tags: .htaccess, mamp

I'm running MAMP 3.2.2 on Windows 10, with Apache on port 8888. I'm trying to password protect the directory C:\MAMP\htdocs\admin\ by placing a .htaccess and a .htpasswd files inside it.

.htacess is:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Password Protected Area"
AuthUserFile C:\MAMP\htdocs\admin\.htpasswd
Require valid-user
```

.htpasswd (user = test; password = test) is:

```
test:dGRkPurkuWmW2
```

I checked MAMP's Apache httpd.conf and it says, in line 202:

```
 <Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks ExecCGI
    AllowOverride All
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

And, in line 220:

```
<Directory "C:\MAMP\htdocs">
    #
    # Possible values for the Options directive are "None", "All",
    # or any combination of:
    #   Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks SymLinksifOwnerMatch ExecCGI MultiViews
    #
    # Note that "MultiViews" must be named *explicitly* --- "Options All"
    # doesn't give it to you.
    #
    # The Options directive is both complicated and important.  Please see
    # http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#options
    # for more information.
    #
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks ExecCGI

    #
    # AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
    # It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
    #   Options FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
    #
    AllowOverride All


    #
    # Controls who can get stuff from this server.
    #
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
```

When trying to navigate to "http://localhost:8888/admin/index.php" I get the "Authentication Required" dialog, saying that "http://localhost:8888 is requesting your username and password". But, after entering username and password, the dialog keeps reappearing, instead of granting me access.

What am I missing?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: The problem was that I was using PHP "$encryptedPassword = crypt($typedPassword, base64_encode($typedPassword));" to create the encoded password, as I would prefer not to depend on using password generators from other sites. Does any one know the right way to encrypt the password?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The password `test:dGRkPurkuWmW2` is wrong. Check the log files (`\mamp\apache\logs\error.log`) to see the error messages, there should be something like this:

```
[Sat Dec 10 10:39:04.965830 2016] [auth_basic:error] [pid 2200:tid 1648] [client ::1:49487] AH01617: user test: authentication failure for "/protected/": Password Mismatch
```

Use this [HTPasswd Generator](http://www.web2generators.com/apache-tools/htpasswd-generator) form to generate a valid password, which in your case for user `test` and password `test` will be something like this, but it always produces something different:

```
test:$apr1$2pi0lu5b$Omg8StTZWO0m5lMfq/D8d.
```

Here is a screen capture with my working example using the password above:

[image: Protected directory login]

**UPDATE**

Note that this algorithm is working for *Windows*. The password you have at your code (`$encryptedPassword = crypt($typedPassword, base64_encode($typedPassword));`) works on *Linux* based systems and it is the default algorithm used by *Apache 2.2.17* and older. From *Apache 2.2.18*, the default encryption method is based on MD5 and it can be used on both *Windows* and *Linux* based systems. You can read more about it here [How to generate passwords for .htpasswd using PHP](https://www.virendrachandak.com/techtalk/using-php-create-passwords-for-htpasswd-file/).

PHP code with the function `crypt_apr1_md5` to generate a `.htpasswd` password entry for `APR1-MD5` encryption compatible for windows:

```
<?php
// APR1-MD5 encryption method (windows compatible)
function crypt_apr1_md5($plainpasswd)
{
    $salt = substr(str_shuffle("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789"), 0, 8);
    $len = strlen($plainpasswd);
    $text = $plainpasswd.'$apr1$'.$salt;
    $bin = pack("H32", md5($plainpasswd.$salt.$plainpasswd));
    for($i = $len; $i > 0; $i -= 16) { $text .= substr($bin, 0, min(16, $i)); }
    for($i = $len; $i > 0; $i >>= 1) { $text .= ($i & 1) ? chr(0) : $plainpasswd{0}; }
    $bin = pack("H32", md5($text));
    for($i = 0; $i < 1000; $i++)
    {
        $new = ($i & 1) ? $plainpasswd : $bin;
        if ($i % 3) $new .= $salt;
        if ($i % 7) $new .= $plainpasswd;
        $new .= ($i & 1) ? $bin : $plainpasswd;
        $bin = pack("H32", md5($new));
    }
    for ($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++)
    {
        $k = $i + 6;
        $j = $i + 12;
        if ($j == 16) $j = 5;
        $tmp = $bin[$i].$bin[$k].$bin[$j].$tmp;
    }
    $tmp = chr(0).chr(0).$bin[11].$tmp;
    $tmp = strtr(strrev(substr(base64_encode($tmp), 2)),
    "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/",
    "./0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz");

    return "$"."apr1"."$".$salt."$".$tmp;
}

// Password to be used for the user
$username = 'test';
$password = 'test';

// Encrypt password
$encrypted_password = crypt_apr1_md5($password);

// Print line to be added to .htpasswd file
echo $username . ':' . $encrypted_password;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Christos. I was trying to create the encrypted password by using "$encryptedPassword = crypt($typedPassword, base64_encode($typedPassword));" in PHP. Do you know what would be the right way to do it?